# setup vim so that it searches the python path

Tags: vim, python

I'm using vim as my primary editor with python files; I'd like to be able to easily open python files.

As an example: I'm looking at a particular module `A.py`, in it I see the line `import funkyModule`, I want to edit that module so I just type in the command `:pyed funkyModule` and the  `pyed` vim-command automatically finds the file `funkyModule.py` (or `funkyModule/__init__.py`) where ever it occurs on the python path.

This capability is modeled on the capabilities if the `ipython` shell, where

`In [#]: edit funkyModule`

does what I've just described.

This [python-vim tip](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Automatically_add_Python_paths_to_Vim_path) does something similar, but doesn't work for `from ...` imports, and I'd just generally prefer it to be analogous to `:ed file_to_open`, which is how I typically open a file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ctags. It indexes your project and can typically be used like this:

```
:tag foo<CR>          " open method/class/variable/whatever foo
:ptag foo<CR>         " open method/class/variable/whatever foo in a preview window
<C-]> on foo(1, 2, 3) " open method/class/variable/whatever foo
etc.
```

See `:help tags`.

Another approach would be to set the `path` option to a value that would work for your project and use the `:find` command.